# regex match nth to last occurence of pattern

Tags: regex

The JSON outputs of an API response reached the character limit, therefore I need to replace everything after the second to last occurence of the character } with closing brackets to format the API response.

String sample:

```
 {"date": "2004", "day": 0, "count": 0, "stage": "arst"}, {"date": "2004", "day": 1, "count": 0, "stage": "oien"}, {"date": "2005
```

Desired output:

```
{"date": "2004", "day": 0, "count": 0, "stage": "arst"}
```

To remove all characters after the last occurence of }, I run this:

```
regexp_replace(response, '[^}]+$', ']}]}')
```

In a Redshift SQL statement, I use the `regexp_replace` function three times to get the desired output:

```
when RIGHT(response, 5) != '}]}]}' then regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(response, '[^}]+$', ''), '[^{]+$', ''), '[^}]+$', ']}]}')
```

How can I match the second to last pattern in a single regex expression?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    regexp_replace(response, '(.*\\})\\s*,\\s*(\\{[^}]+\\})$', '\\1\\n\\2') AS modified_response
FROM your_table;
```

1. (.*}) captures everything up to the last } before the
   second-to-last }.
2. \s*,\s* matches the comma and any surrounding whitespace.
3. ({[^}]+}) captures the content between the second-to-last } and
   the last }.

Comment: Doesn't work in the code or in regex101